# Função sendo executada a partir do segundo clique

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um botão no meu projeto, o qual a função é fazer aparecer uma div que está como display none, porém a função só é executada a partir do segundo clique no botão, no primeiro clique apenas seleciona o botão. Alguém saberia me informar o que estou fazendo errado?

Segue prints:

Tela:

**Botão:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Primeiro clique: (Botão selecionado)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segundo clique: (Div aparece)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn botaoGlobalLeft" ng-click="$ctrl.intermediacao()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span> Intermediação</button>

<div class="elemento form-group row" id="intermediacao">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label for="apelido2">Apelido</label>
            <input type="text" title="Informe o apelido" id="apelido2" class="form-control inputEstoque">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#informacoes{
display: none;
}
```

**JS (Angular):**

```
intermediacao() {
  const display = document.getElementById("intermediacao").style.display;
  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById("intermediacao").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("intermediacao").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, poderia digitar seu código na pergunta. Use a opção Amostra de código **`{}`** para formatar seu código. A imagem do código atrapalha muito para quem for responder.

Comment: Editado, valeu pela dica

Comment: Não é legal manipular as classes do elemento diretamente no código com `Angular`

Comment: Já removi meu voto negativo, mas para me justificar referente ao quando votei negativo: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Tranquilo, é que sou novo por aqui, e não irei fazer isso novamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um elemento com `display: none` direto no CSS, não possui valor *inline*, que é o que se pega com `document.getElementById("intermediacao").style.display`.

Por isso no primeiro *click* o elemento ganha o estilo `none` *inline* e no segundo click já irá funcionar.

Para resolver isso, insira no `if` uma segunda condição para verificar se é vazio:

```
if (display == "none" || display == "") {...
```